# Lists in Rails sites

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, plugins, rubygems

Is there a special way to create lists from models in rails that allows for special/dynamic sorting or reording/responding live as users interact with them? (Editing text, reording, etc...).

All I could find online was this: https://github.com/javve/list which is in javascript.

Are there any rails specific plugins or gems I haven't found yet? If no Rails gems/plugins exist does this mean I'll have to use JS (ajax)?

Thanks

(Just to clarify, I don't want lists/arrays as a datatype but rather lists on the front-end)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [acts_as_list](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/acts_as_list)? [Ruby toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/) is a great resource for finding gems.